# Spring 3 + atmosphere - type AtmosphereResource is not generic

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, atmosphere

I am getting Error of (**The type AtmosphereResource is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments** ) during implementation of the following method in my spring 3 controller.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/websockets", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     @ResponseBody
     public void websockets(final AtmosphereResource<HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse> event) {

          final HttpServletRequest  req = event.getRequest();
            final HttpServletResponse res = event.getResponse();
            event.suspend();

            final Broadcaster bc = event.getBroadcaster();
            bc.scheduleFixedBroadcast(new Callable<String>() {

                public String call() throws Exception {

                    return (new Date()).toString();
                }
            }, 11, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably figured the answer, but `AtmosphereResource<?,?>` no longer exists starting with 0.9 and higher version. Just remove that and it will works.

Comment: BeanInstantiationException for AtmosphereResource. Please help!

Comment: Jump to the Atmosphere mailing list...or try 2.1.0-RC1 and read https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Configuring-Atmosphere's-Classes-Creation-and-Injection